# How to add 2 templates for joomla 2.5 modules

Tags: joomla

I want to build my first module for Joomla 2.5 but I have a problem. I want to have multiple templates for my module, and the admin of the site can choose the templates from the config of the module. How can I do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple templates for your module" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are planning to create a joomla 2.5 front end module.then you can achieve your requirement as follows

You can use the joomla module override concept.
For each template you are using you can write module inside template folder for overrides.

like as follows 
TEMPLATE_NAME/html/mod_login/default.php

for more details [take a look at this](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

I hope this will solve your issues..